# Icon Size and color

Tags: lightning-web-components, css, html, svg-icon, lds

Hi Kindly help me out for the below , i need to alligned the icon properly with the text next to it
and make it red color ,,, kindly help me out for this.

code:

```
<lightning-button-icon class='slds button'
  icon-name='utility:warning' variant='bare' ></lightning-button-icon>
  Action
```

below is the image
[image]

kindly someone help me out for this.
thanks

Comment: Do you want to display icon on the button?

Comment: not required...i can display without button...buy size should be like that of text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put some top margin on the text Use `slds-text-color_destructive` to change the text color to red.
And to align the items use `slds-float_left` with some padding.

To change icon color to red use `icon-class="slds-text-color_destructive"` on `lightning-button-icon`.

```
<div>
    <lightning-button-icon icon-class="slds-text-color_destructive" class='slds-float_left slds-var-p-top_xxx-small' icon-name='utility:warning' variant='bare'></lightning-button-icon>
    <div class="slds-float_left slds-var-p-top_xx-small slds-var-p-left_xx-small slds-text-color_destructive">Action</div>
</div>
```

Comment: thankyu so much  ,,, but i need t change the icon as red color....can you suggest anythig for this

Comment: @Tina check now